# Ridge and Lasso Regression: Should I drop one reference category like in OLS?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, lasso, ridge-regression, regularization

I do a ridge and lasso regression with a data set that have categorial variables.
Should i drop 1 reference category like in OLS or is it okay to run the regression with als categories as dummy variables?